# Errors running blender in Ubuntu 20.04 WSL

Tags: python, error

I'm trying to run a test for a [repository](https://github.com/RahhulDd/FbxToNpyConverter) that requires blender. Blender is installed, I created a venv with `numpy` installed, and I've navigated to the repository's directory to run a test but I receive a traceback for an error:

```
(venv_w_numpy) me@my_pc:~/FbxToNpyConverter$ blender --background -P fbx2npy.py
Blender 2.82 (sub 7)
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/FbxToNpyConverter/fbx2npy.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Again, my conda environment `venv_w_numpy` has `numpy` installed and is activated. Does blender require it's own special type of environment? I'm new to blender and to this repository, but it seems like the error is caused by something with blender.

Comment: You shouldn't need to install numpy. Blender ships with its own Python interpreter with numpy preinstalled. Unless you need a venv for something else, it should not be necessary to use one.

Comment: I'll clarify to say that I tried creating a venv with numpy installed after getting this error, and that, of course in retrospect, the venv does not help. I'm wondering why the blender-shipped python interpreter is insufficient and causing this ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: There seem to be other issues preceding this. I would suggest you do a clean setup with an [official release of Blender](https://download.blender.org/release/). Remove existing config files in `~/.config/blender/2.82`. Issues might also be caused by add-ons.